# ERRO no INSTER MYSQL PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert

Estou tentando fazer um insert utilizando o PHP PDO, mas ele sempre está retornando um erro, que não estou sabendo resolver

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO usuarios ('usuario', 'senha', 'telefone', 'email', 'tipo', 'status', 'nivel', 'hash') VALUES (:usuario, :senha, :telefone, :email, :tipo, :status, :nivel, :hash)";

    try{
        $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
        $result->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':senha', $senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':telefone', $telefone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':tipo', $tipo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':nivel', $nivel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':hash', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $result->execute();
        $contar = $result->rowCount();
        if($contar>0){
            $ret['status'] = "OK";
        }else{
            $ret['status'] = "ERRO";
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
    }
```

e está retornando o seguinte errro:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''usuario', 'senha', 'telefone', 'email', 'tipo', 'status', 'nivel', 'hash') VALU' at line 1 in /var/www/html/trocadex/src/php/cadastro.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/trocadex/src/php/cadastro.php(32): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

não precisa de aspas nas colunas "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, senha, telefone, email, tipo, status, nivel, hash) VALUES (:usuario, :senha, :telefone, :email, :tipo, :status, :nivel, :hash)"